# How to give a value to the function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using code igniter, how can I give the output of my query to the function returnQuery? Then pass that value to my controller.

```
public function returnQuery() {
 $sql = "SELECT USERCODE FROM tbl_users where USERNAME =? AND PASSWORD = ?";
 $data = array(
  'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
  'PASSWORD' => $this->input->post('PASSWORD')
 );
 $query = $this->db->query($sql, $data);
}
```

Comment: return `$query` at the end

Comment: then i can pass the value to the controllers through $this->login_model->returnQuery(); ??

Comment: for that you will need  $this->login_model->returnQuery()->result() and use $this->login_model->returnQuery()->num_rows() to get no. of rows returned.

Comment: i need the value of the query..  what i am trying to do is, 

`$q = $this->login_model->returnQuery();

   if ($q == 1){

    redirect('login/adminIndex');

   }elseif ($q == 2) {

    redirect('login/userIndex');

   }else{

    redirect('login/restricted');
    
   }
`

but then again , whatever happens it redirects to == 1 even tho it should be redirected to == 2. theres an instance where i changed ($q == '1') it redirected to restricted page.

Comment: Use it as $q = $this->login_model->returnQuery()->row()->USERCODE;

Comment: it still returns true on =1 tho it must return false and return true on =2.

Comment: There seems to be a lack of programming experience since doing such thing is basic PHP. I don't mean any offence but I'd recommend trying to use OOP first a little bit as it will help you more than jumping into MVC right away.

Comment: yes. i am a new into using mvc.

Comment: I have added my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can return any function's value just like core PHP in CodeIgniter.

Modify line:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $data);
```

To:

```
return $this->db->query($sql, $data);
```

Notice that I have removed `$query` assignment as it is not used anywhere.

We can return data without it.

Comment: then i can pass the value to the controllers through $this->login_model->returnQuery(); ??

Comment: @kev_m yes where u calling store it into variable and than use variable for getting values $data = $this->login_model->returnQuery(); print_r($data);

Comment: @devpro i need it for this can you please help?    `$q = $this->login_model->returnQuery();

    if ($q = '1'){

     redirect('login/adminIndex');

    }elseif ($q = '2') {

     redirect('login/userIndex');

    }else{

     redirect('login/restricted');
    
   }` thanks.

Comment: @kev_m I have added an answer chk it

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments you can return data as:

```
public function returnQuery() 
{ 
    $sql = "SELECT USERCODE FROM tbl_users where USERNAME =? AND PASSWORD = ?"; 
    $data = array( 'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'), 'PASSWORD' => $this->input->post('PASSWORD') ); 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $data);
    $result = $query->result_array();
    if(count($result) > 0){
       return $result[0]["USERCODE"];
    }
    else{
       return 0;
    }
}
```

**And now how can you use redirection:**

```
//call function
$q = $this->login_model->returnQuery(); 
if ($q == 1){ 
     redirect('login/adminIndex'); 
}
elseif ($q == 2) { 
     redirect('login/userIndex'); 
}
else{
     redirect('login/restricted');
}
```

**Note that** in your code you are not comparing the values you are assigning 
`if ($q = 1)` this should be `if ($q == 1)`

Comment: is it supposed to be $q == 1 or $q == '1'

Comment: U can use both but I suggest to use $q == 1 becuase 1 is not a string @kev_m

Comment: it still isnt working it still is redirecting me to restricted page. then i purposedly changed it to $q = 1 so it would redirect to my admin and the print_r($this->login_model->returnQuery()); returned just 0.. i tried  return $result["USERCODE"]; and  return $result[0]; , but nothing worked. :(

Comment: @kev_m my friend your query is returning empty result

Comment: Thatsway u r getting 0 this is the big difference between = and == u can't use = @kev_m

Comment: no i just did it to run the  print_r($this->login_model->returnQuery()); on my admin page. and the  print_r($this->login_model->returnQuery()); gives back 0.. it means that the function returnQuery just returns 0..

Comment: @kev_m if   if(count($result) > 0) return 0 it means u don't have any row against your username password in database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102714/discussion-between-devpro-and-kev-m).

Comment: @kev_m come on chat or use this SELECT USERCODE FROM tbl_users where USERNAME = "yourusername" AND PASSWORD = "yourpassword" in phpmyadmin u will get the idea your query return 0 record